# Qt SLOT not triggered by the SIGNAL emitted from std::async in QTest environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I was investigating the topic of async programming with Qt and I reached the conclusion that it is safe to emit signals from whatever kind of threads (although QT docs only mention `QThread`), as more or less described [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html). Now I faced the problem testing my application. To simplify as much as possible: I have the async operation, which might notify `MainWindow` by emitting the SIGNAL. It works fine in the production, but it doesn't work in unit-test environment with `QTest`. Complete example (project structure flat, no subdirs):

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(QtFailure)

enable_testing()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Test REQUIRED)

add_library(QtFailure source.cpp header.hpp)
target_include_directories(QtFailure PUBLIC .)
target_link_libraries(QtFailure
  pthread
  Qt5::Core
  Qt5::Widgets
)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main QtFailure)

add_executable(QtFailureTest test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(QtFailureTest
  QtFailure
  Qt5::Test
)
```

`header.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>

#include <future>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
  ~MainWindow();
  void start();
  int counter_value();

signals:
  void sendSignal();

private slots:
  bool triggerSlot();

private:
  bool stop_;
  std::future<void> async_oper_;
};
```

`source.cpp`

```
#include "header.hpp"

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

static int counter = 0;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent):
  QMainWindow(parent),
  stop_(false),
  async_oper_()
{
  QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(sendSignal()), this, SLOT(triggerSlot()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  stop_ = true;
}

int MainWindow::counter_value()
{
  return counter;
}

void MainWindow::start()
{
  if (async_oper_.valid()) return;
  emit sendSignal();  // this one works
  async_oper_ = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]()
  {
    while (!stop_)
    {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
      emit sendSignal();  // this one doesn't work in tests
    }
  });
}

bool MainWindow::triggerSlot()
{
  qDebug() << "triggerSlot: " << counter;
  counter++;
}
```

`test.cpp`

```
#include "header.hpp"

#include <QSignalSpy>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtTest/QtTest>

#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class MyFixture: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
private:
  std::unique_ptr<MainWindow> sut_;

private slots:
  void init()
  {
    qDebug("MyFixture init");
    sut_.reset(new MainWindow);
  }
  void cleanup()
  {
    qDebug("MyFixture cleanup");
    sut_.reset();
  }
  void example_test()
  {
    QSignalSpy spy(sut_.get(), SIGNAL(sendSignal()));
    sut_->start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    qDebug() << "num signals: " << spy.count();
    qDebug() << "counter value: " << sut_->counter_value();
  }
};

QTEST_MAIN(MyFixture)
#include "test.moc"
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "header.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.start();
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

The output from my test is

```
PASS   : MyFixture::initTestCase()
QDEBUG : MyFixture::example_test() MyFixture init
QDEBUG : MyFixture::example_test() triggerSlot:  0
QDEBUG : MyFixture::example_test() num signals:  10
QDEBUG : MyFixture::example_test() counter value:  1
QDEBUG : MyFixture::example_test() MyFixture cleanup
PASS   : MyFixture::example_test()
PASS   : MyFixture::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 1003ms
```

which means that the slot was triggered only once, by the signal emitted from the main thread.

The output from main is:

```
...
triggerSlot:  25
triggerSlot:  26
triggerSlot:  27
etc ...
```

which is the expected behavior. Why is there a difference between QTest environment and normal QApplication in main? What should I do to correct tests behavior?

I must use standard C++ threads, because my GUI is just a facade to real non-Qt related system, which has different kinds of async opers, callbacks etc.

Sorry for the amount of code, but with QT I cannot really squeeze it in a few lines.

=== EDIT ===

Specifying `Qt::DirectConnection` connection attribute will "fix" the issue in the QTest environment. But this is something I cannot do in most cases, because GUI actions must take place in the main thread (e.g. scync oper emits signal to trigger QPixmap refresh);

Comment: `Qt::QueuedConnection`

Comment: Also, prefer modern connection syntax that is checked at compile-time to make sure the slot and signal names are correct: `connect(this, &MainWindow::sendSignal, this, &MainWindow::triggerSlot, Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Comment: @NikosC. yeah that was the first thing I tried. Doesn't work. Default connection type "should" default to `Qt::QueuedConnection` for the signal from another thread anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal emit code is correct. Queued Signal-Slot connection requires [event loop to be running **in the receiver thread** for signal delivery:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop)

> Events to that object are dispatched by that (receiver) thread's event loop.

Event loop of the receiver thread aren't working because you block it in the line

```
// just suspends current thread without running any event loop
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

That is, event loop of the receiver thread are blocking throughout the whole `example_test()` method body. There is no one line which runs an event loop within itself. **That is not Qt Test or QTEST_MAIN() issue.**

Here is how you can fix that:

```
void example_test()
  {
    QSignalSpy spy(sut_.get(), SIGNAL(sendSignal()));
    sut_->start(); 

    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();

    while(timer.elapsed() < 1000)
    {
        spy.wait(10); // event loop runs here
    }

    qDebug() << "num signals: " << spy.count();
    qDebug() << "counter value: " << sut_->counter_value();
  }
```

[QSignalSpy::wait()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html#wait):

> Starts an event loop that runs until the given signal is received.
>   Optionally the event loop can return earlier on a timeout (in
>   milliseconds).
>
> Returns true if the signal was emitted at least once in timeout milliseconds, otherwise returns false.

Comment: Thanks. Super confusing that QTest documentation. I was sure that event loop in QTest is started by `qExec`, which is called from `QTEST_MAIN` macro.

Comment: @pptaszni be note that it was not a `QTEST_MAIN` issue. See edits.

Comment: Mhmm I see. Then I guess `std::condition_variable::wait_for` has the same problem as `sleep`. Fortunately there is `QTest::qWaitFor(Functor predicate, int timeout = 5000)`